# Office 365 Developer Subscription & Yammer Delve

Tags: office-365, yammer

I subscribed to Office 365 developer account, and paid 99$ for a yearly subscription, do I have Yammer and Delve in my account? I want to start learning them, what do I do? How can I see features related to developer account?

Do I need to have E3 plan to learn Yammer?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can sign up for Yammer, however you must be invited to join a network.  In order to create a network you must have Yammer Enterprise.  Yammer Enterprise is available with O365 Business/Education or as a standalone service.  Existing O365 Enterprise/Mid-Sized Business/Education plans [may be entitled to upgrade to Yammer Enterprise](https://about.yammer.com/pricing/).

If you just want to learn to develop with the Yammer SDK, you technically can get started with your developer account, and just join the Office 365 Community network.  However, you would probably benefit from an Enterprise account.  [Here](https://developer.yammer.com/documentation/) is more info on Yammer development.

Delve is a BI tool powered by the Office graph.  In order to get started using Delve, you must be part of the first release group and activate the required O365 plans and services.  Delve and the Office graph are available for O365 Enterprise (E1, E3 and E4), Education (A2, A3 and A4) and Government (G1, G3 and G4).  Regardless of the plans you have, the SharePoint Online service must be activated, and users must have a SharePoint Online license assigned.  [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delve-for-Office-365-admins-54f87a42-15a4-44b4-9df0-d36287d9531b) is more info on Delve and the Office graph.

Not sure what you mean by 'learn', but a different plan may be required.

Comment: Thanks, what I mean by learn is to know the capabilities and integration points between Yammer and SharePoint, and how can I benefit from it within my intranet, so I have developer account from Office 365, but am not sure if it provides this. Do I need to have trial subscription from E plans?

Answer (score 0):

I think Yammer is available, you can try to activate it using

https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/activation-guide/add-a-company-domain/

Or use the Basic Feature of Yammer which is free

https://about.yammer.com/pricing/

You can find the list of available feature from the Office 365 Admin center.

To compare different plans you can visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-365-plan-options.aspx

Comment: I tried to activate Yammer, I saw a link on Office 365, it redirects me to the login page of Office 365 again, and when I login nothing happens, so I guess it's not provided with developer subscription?